# Delete using Yammer API Issue - “Rate limited due to excessive requests.”

Tags: ajax, sharepoint-online, office365api, yammer, rest

While delete a comment, I can delete two comments back to back but when I tried to delete next comment(3rd comment). It shows error in console **“Rate limited due to excessive requests.”** But after few seconds when I try to delete, it works fine for next two comments. I have tried to use “wait” function for few seconds to make it work but there is inconsistency in result. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn’t.
My code as follows,

```
function deleteComment(MessagePostId) {
    var result = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Comment?");
    if (result) {
        yam.platform.request({
            url: "https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/" + MessagePostId,
            method: "DELETE",
            async: false,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', token) },
            success: function (res) {
                alert("The Comment has been deleted.");
                //Code to remove item from array and display rest of the comment to screen
            },
            error: function (res) {
                alert("Please try again after some time.");
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting [rate limits](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/rest-api-rate-limits) which prevent multiple deletion requests from a regular user like those which you've hit. The API is designed for client applications where you perhaps make an occasional deletion, but aren't deleting in bulk.

To handle rate limits, you need to update your code to check the response value in the `res` variable. If it's an HTTP 429 response then you are being rate limited and need to wait before retrying the original request.

Comment: Thanks @BrianLyttle ..!! It seems reasonable.